# How do I choose a package for tukey ANOVA post-test?

Tags: r, posthoc, tukey

So I have done a Tukey post test for a two-way ANOVA using both agricolae's *HSD.test* and the *TukeyHSD*.

The *HSD.test* gave me the feature combinations, their mean y-values, standard deviation, min, max, and quartile values. It then puts combinations of features into groups A, B, BC and C based on similarities and differences. When I plot these it plots the means and standard deviations of each group.

```
a3=aov(Delta.~Loc*between, data=m3)
 tx <- with(m3, interaction(Loc, between))
 amod <- aov(Delta.~tx, data=m3)
 library(agricolae)
 HSD.test(amod, "tx", group=TRUE)
```

[image: mean and standard deviation using HSD.test]

The *TukeyHSD* compares within each feature and then compares combinations of features. For each comparison it gives the difference the lower and upper ranges and the adjusted p-values. If I plot this data it gives me the 95% confidence interval for each comparison and there are a lot of blanks.

```
TukeyHSD(a3)
```

[image: 95% confidence internal using TukeyHSD]

How do I know which package's Tukey test to use? 
Are there others? 
If I use the `TukeyHSD` can I drop all the blank comparisons?

Comment: You need to show your code. The plot from `HSD.test` indicates 8 groups, with 2 of them very small. For 8 groups there are 8*7/2 = 28 comparisons so you should have 28 lines in the `TukeyHSD` plot, but there are many more so something is wrong.

Comment: Well I have 2 features and each feature has 3 or 10 different levels, depending on the dataset. So there can be many combinations.
My understanding is that HSD.test groups my data so if feature combinations produce similar results they will be in one group (which I very useful) but TukeyHSD just compares all possible combinations. In this case many combinations are missing before I have not tested them.

Comment: Not exactly. The groups identified by the multiple comparisons analysis can be overlapping, e.g. for 3 groups groups 1 and 2 could be not significantly different from one another and groups 2 and 3 could be not significantly different from one another so you have two groups but the share one member. One way of identifying the groups is to use a compact letter display. in the example, group 1 would be "a", group 2 would be "ab", and group 3 would be "c". That feature is available in the `multcomp` package. There is a very helpful vignette for the package with examples using the Tukey test.